# Adding multi-tenancy to a Java EE application

Tags: jpa, ejb, multi-tenant

I already have an application using *Java EE* deployed in *Glassfish* and I want to add multi-tenancy so that it can support many tenants.

I'm using the following technologies: *EJB, JPA (EclipseLink) and JSF*

during my research I found three approaches for managing multi-tenant data (persistence layer):

1. Separate databases
2. Shared Database, Separate Schemas
3. Shared Database, Shared Schema

*Which approach do you recommand and how can other layers be affected by multi-tenance?*